# Is there any tool to show me where webpage contents come from?

Tags: html, http, web-applications, web

When I request a webpage, I actually make lots of requests for imgs, banners, javascripts (js can include others js and so on), iframes, css, plugins, activex, applets,...

How can I get the url's list I'm actually downloading from?

Comment: [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) is a pretty standard tool for this too..

Comment: Thanks everybody. All that stuff just under my nose!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way is to use your browser's built-in development tools.  Generally look for the "network" tab.

[image: Google Chrome Network Panel]

*(Google Chrome's [Network Panel](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/network))*

You can also use a tool such as [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/), which acts as a proxy server and shows you all web requests, even HTTP from other applications.

Comment: Agreed with this. Webkit browsers (Safari, Chrome) have great built-in tools. The Firebug plugin for Firefox is great too. Both tools should be in your toolkit.

Comment: In IE9 or later, hit F12 and click the NETWORK Tab. The advantage of Fiddler is that it works with ALL browsers, and you can also modify the traffic.